# JSON Parse Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json-framework, sbjson

I am using SBJson framework (also known as json-framework) for the iOS.

When parsing a certain JSON file, I am getting the following error:
 **-JSONValue failed. Error is: Unescaped control character [0x09]**'

I have used this framework many times and I am also parsing a very similar JSON file (that is even much longer) in that same app and it's working fine.

I tried throwing around a bunch of NSLogs and everything seems to be fine. Can someone please point me to what this error means, or at least how to go ahead in debugging such an error?

Here is the code that displays the error:

```
- (void)downloadSchedule:(NSString *)jsonString {

    // Get JSON feed URL and instantiate a dictionary object with its content
    NSDictionary *topDic = [jsonString JSONValue];

    NSLog(@"topDic count %d", [topDic count]);
```

topDic is showing a count of 0. The error is at the `[jsonString JSONValue]` line.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your file contain an unencoded tab (ascii `0x09`) that should be replaced with `\t` according to the [json](http://www.json.org/) grammar.

Answer (score 8):

I have a great solution for it. Apply this method for remove escaped characters.

```
-(NSString *)removeUnescapedCharacter:(NSString *)inputStr
{

NSCharacterSet *controlChars = [NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet];

NSRange range = [inputStr rangeOfCharacterFromSet:controlChars];

  if (range.location != NSNotFound) 
  {

      NSMutableString *mutable = [NSMutableString stringWithString:inputStr];

      while (range.location != NSNotFound) 
      {

          [mutable deleteCharactersInRange:range];

          range = [mutable rangeOfCharacterFromSet:controlChars];

      }

      return mutable;

   }

  return inputStr;
}
```

Call this method with passing your output string like this

```
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourUrlString"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

output = [self removeUnescapedCharacter:output];
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable.

Comment: No. The correct solution is to fix the source of the invalid JSON, not to work around it with hacks like this.

Comment: But for valid JSON we can fix it on both PHP and I-Phone side for more secure JSON parsing.

Comment: I just used this to solve my problem.  How do I know which character was causing the issue? Because it was working fine up until a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.json.org/ There are some characters that need to be escaped to be properly parsed by JSON. This is the cause. The file is not proper JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is having  '\n' or '\r' kind of html qoutes then it may cause error in obj-c.
You can add :

`[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@"<br />"]`

I was having same problem and solved using this.