# AFNetworking JSON request not working

Tags: php, ios, json, afnetworking

I'm trying to start this operation and its not even getting to the NSLOG.
I guess its something with my stringUrl, maybe its not suppose to work like this?

This is my code:

```
NSString *stringUrl = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://example.com/add_user.php?username=%@&password=%@&country=%@&email=%@",[self.usernameTextField text],[self.passwordTextField text], countrySelected, [self.emailTextField text]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSDictionary *dict = JSON;
    NSLog(@"IP Address: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"item"]);
} failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

Edit:
this is what i got from the failure block:

> Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript"
>   )}, got text/html" UserInfo=0xa2b4300 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"type":"1","item": "User added successfully."}
>   , AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://EXAMPLE.com/add_user.php?username=aaasafasfasf&password=aaa&country=Angola&email=aaaasfasfasfasfasf>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://EXAMPLE.com/add_user.php?username=aaasafasfasf&password=aaa&country=Angola&email=aaaasfasfasfasfasf, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
>       "text/json",
>       "application/json",
>       "text/javascript"
>   )}, got text/html, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

Comment: Get value for stringUrl with NSLog and paste in your browser, and see what is the result.

Comment: @edzio27 this is what I get:
{"type": "0","item":"Username already exists Email already exists "} 
and it what I wanted to get but its not even gets to the NSLog

Comment: Could you try to use the failure block?

Comment: Does the browser change any encoding in the string? Particularly in the email address?

Comment: @verbumdei Edited and now include the failure block.

Comment: Well, you need to set the content type returned to be text/json or application/json instead of the current one text/html: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919584/how-to-change-content-type-in-php. AFNetworking is quite strict with the content type, I believe :)

Comment: @Wain its not a real email now, I can enter even aaaaaa as an email.

Comment: @verbumdei Change this header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *') to this: header('Content-Type: text/json'); ?

Comment: no need to replace, you can add it below the existing `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get into the success block of the AFJSONRequestOperation, you also need to adhere to the correct content type to be sent by the server. Currently your server is returning *text/html* content type as the response, hence it goes into the failure block.

As the failure block message suggests, change the content type returned to be *text/json* or *application/json* since you are using the AFJSONRequestOperation.

For PHP, you can change the content type returned by following the answer in this question: [How to change content type in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919584/how-to-change-content-type-in-php)

You can just add one additional line below your existing header lines:

```
header('Content-Type: text/json');
```

No need to replace existing header lines unless there is a header line to set content type into something else other than *text/json* or *application/json*.

Comment: now I have another problem:
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 45.) UserInfo=0xa361a40 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 45.}
 I think that the NSURL is too long.

Comment: @RotemShukron you will need to check the JSON returned whether it is a valid JSON. You can try the suggestions found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966349/json-parse-error